# django webfaction: No module named dateutil.relativedelta

Tags: python, django, webfaction

I just uploaded my project to be hosted on webfaction and am getting the following error.

```
No module named dateutil.relativedelta
```

I'm using this module in one of my forms. Is this something to do with the python path?

Comment: Are you using PIP to manage dependencies? Perhaps `dateutil` was installed into your local `site-packages` directory which doesn't exist on the server.

Comment: Yes, PIP and easy_install. When I run "pip install python-dateutil" on the server i get this...

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): python-dateutil in /home/username/lib/python2.4/python_dateutil-2.1-py2.4.egg
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six in /home/username/lib/python2.4/six-1.1.0-py2.4.egg (from python-dateutil)

Comment: python2.4? Are you sure that's the version of python being used for your django project?

Comment: I'm almost positive it's python2.7. About 95% sure. Does python path have anything to do with this?I tried to upload my "site-packages" directory but that didn't do anything

Comment: The problem most likely is that django is running under python2.7, but your pip is currently installing for python2.4. I've not used webfaction so I don't know how it's managed. You might want to change your bash_profile so that python2.7 comes before python2.4 in your path. This isn't a problem with pythonpath - it's a problem with the installed python version.

Comment: Following @Josh comment, check out: http://docs.webfaction.com/software/python.html

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me on Ubuntu when Eclipse gave the same error:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dateutil
```